# Looping with dynamic class

Tags: c#, class

I have this code:

```
public class TABLE01
{
    public string FIELD1 { get; set; }
    public string FIELD2 { get; set; }
}
...
// fieldlist:
List<string> fieldsTABLE01 = new List<string>();
fieldsTABLE01.Add("FIELD1");
fieldsTABLE01.Add("FIELD2");

//response type List:
lResponseLegacy.Clear();
lResponseLegacy = DataExtract(fieldsTABLE01);

List<ClassDefinitions.TABLE01> listDataTableTABLE01 = new List<ClassDefinitions.TABLE01>();
foreach (string linea in lResponseLegacy)
{
    ClassDefinitions.TABLE01 tableTABLE01 = new ClassDefinitions.TABLE01();
    tableTABLE01.table01FIELD1 = ClassPackSupport.GetStringBetween(linea, "<FIELD1>", "</FIELD1>");
    tableTABLE01.table01FIELD2 = ClassPackSupport.GetStringBetween(linea, "<FIELD2>", "</FIELD2>");
    listDataTableTABLE01.Add(tableTABLE01);
}
classRespuestaDataclassModelo.tableTABLE01 = listDataTableTABLE01;
```

Now, I need to use the same previous code for others tables like `fieldsTABLE01` with their own fields. As well, the previous code must create a list from a dynamic definition of a class (`ClassDefinitions.TABLE01`) and loop through of their own fields on these class.

In other words, I need to use the same code (maybe on a method) for other classes:

```
public class TABLE02
{
    public string FIELD3 { get; set; }
    public string FIELD4 { get; set; }
    public string FIELD9 { get; set; }
}


public class TABLE03
{
    public string FIELD5 { get; set; }
    public string FIELD6 { get; set; }
}


public class TABLE04
{
    public string FIELD7 { get; set; }
    public string FIELD8 { get; set; }
    public string FIELD14 { get; set; }
    public string FIELD15 { get; set; }
}
```

Please, do you give me some tip?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)? Seems like it will be useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection like so

```
//Get a classes properties, you can do this with many classes.
var yourClassProperties = typeof(YourClass).GetProperties();

//And down the line:

fieldsTABLE01 = fieldsTABLE01.Concat(yourClassProperties).ToList();
```

Comment: if my classes are on a reference (classdefinitions.dll), how can loop through all classes on classdefinitions.dll?

Comment: You can get an assemblies information, so it's public classes as well